# Call Craft controller with cron job

Tags: plugin-development, controller, cron

I am making a plugin which has a controller to be called every hour.
My server environment is using **Anacron**.

So I wrote this anacron job:
`1@hourly 0 cron.hourly wget http://www.mydomain.com/actions/controlername`

And I got 2 questions:

1. How to log my cron job into a file on the server? (so I can follow when it has been triggered)
2. What is the best way to log and follow my controller actions in Craft CP side?

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your second question:

> 2. What is the best way to log and follow my controller actions in Craft CP side?

You can log actions to a plugin-specific log file like this:

```
MyPluginNamePlugin::log('Controller action triggered', LogLevel::Info, true);
```

Setting the third parameter to `true` forces the logging to happen, even if you are not in `devMode`.

The log file can be found in the `craft/storage/runtime/logs/` directory and will be called `mypluginname.log`.

To view logs in the CP visit `/admin/utils/logs`